# Deduce that Bd$(A)=\overline{A}-\text{Int}(A)$.

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

My textbook defines the boundary of $A$ as Bd$(A)=\overline{A} \cap \overline{A^c}$. 
Deduce that Bd$(A)=\overline{A}-\text{Int}(A)$.

$\textbf{Proof:}$ $(\implies)$ We know that Bd$(A) \subset \overline{A}$, int$(A) \subset A \subset \overline{A}$, and Bd$(A) \cap$ int$(A) = \emptyset$.

Thus, let $x \in$ Bd$(A)$. Then $x \in \overline{A} -$ int$(A)$.

$(\impliedby)$ Let $a \in \overline{A}-$int$(A) \implies a \not \in$ int$(A)$.

So, $a \in G \subset A$ where $G$ is open and $\exists a \neq b$ where $b \in G$ and $b \not \in A$.

$\therefore a \in$ Bd$(A)$.

$\therefore$ Bd$(A)=\overline{A}-$int$(A)$. $\blacksquare$

---

Some remarks that were left on my proof were:

- Why is Bd$(A)-$int$(A)= \emptyset$?
- When you "Let $a \in \overline{A}-$int$(A)$," this makes $a$ specific, so you can't say $\exists a$.
- Finally, "$a \in G \subset A$ where $G$ is open," but $a \not \in$int$(A)$?

---

Any help with the remarks and the proof will be very helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is heard to follow your second direction of the proof. I will write my proof here. $C(A)=\mathbb R\setminus A$ let $a\in \overline A-\text{int(A)}$ then $a\in \overline A$ and $a\notin \text{int}A$. So, $a\notin\text{int}A$ implies that  for all open set $G$ such that $a\in G$ we have $a\in G\not\subset A$ . This means $G\cap C(A)\neq\emptyset$. So, $a\in\overline {C(A)}.$ Hence. $a\in\text{Bd}(A)).$ Another way to see it. By using the very important result which is $$\text{int(A)}=C(\overline{(C(A)})$$ Your lemma, we will follow immediately from  that.